# Combine multiple has_child to single has_child Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch-5

I have a type in elasticsearch **type_1** in which it has only two fields name and value.
I have following elasticsearch query, Is there any alternative of below query that produce same result using only one **has_child** ?

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "has_child": {
                  "type": "type_1",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "name": "field_1"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "value": "val1"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "has_child": {
                  "type": "type_1",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "name": "field_2"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "value": "val2"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```